# gojs+ customising picture based on some data condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gojs

I have a go.picture , but design can be changes based on same attribute value , so how can I customize based on data.

say for example

```
$(go.Picture, {
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  source: '../img/cat.svg',
  imageAlignment: go.Spot.Top,
  alignment: go.Spot.Right,
}),
```

here I have a set of nodes data in nodeDataArray, and if the name is cat , then the cource should be

**source: '../img/cat.svg',**

and if the name property in nodes array is dog , source should dynamically changes to **source: '../img/dog.svg',**

Imagine this is my data

```
   const data = {
      nodeDataArray: [
        { key: 0, name: "Cat", color: "lightblue", loc: "0 0" },
        { key: 1, name: "Dog", color: "orange", loc: "150 0" },

      ],
      linkDataArray: [
        { key: -1, from: 0, to: 1 },
        { key: -2, from: 0, to: 2 },

      ],
      skipsDiagramUpdate: false
    };
```

Any help is highly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data-binding bound to the `data.name` property:

```
$(go.Picture,
  {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    source: '../img/default.svg', // This image will display if data.name does not exist
    imageAlignment: go.Spot.Top,
    alignment: go.Spot.Right,
  },
  // Note carefully that this binding ONLY runs if data.name is specified
  new go.Binding("source", "name", function(name){
    if (name === "Dog") return '../img/dog.svg';
    else if (name === "Cat") return '../img/cat.svg';
    else return '../img/unknown.svg';
  })
  )
```

Don't use an empty-string data binding unless you have to, since they have to evaluate on every data change, they are slower.

Answer (score 0):

````
          go.Picture,
          {
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            margin: new go.Margin(2, 5, 2, 22),
          },
          new go.Binding('source', '', (sourceData, target, name) => {
            if (sourceData.name.includes('cat') > -1) {
              return '../assets/img/cat.svg';
            } else return '../assets/img/dog.svg';
          })
            ),```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).